# Adding values in to a HashMap

Tags: java, arrays, string, hashmap

I need help to add the values from a String array into a HashMap.

```
if (!loaded){
    synchronized(syncLock){
        if (!loaded){
            loaded=true;
            if (prefix!=null){
            prefixMap = new HashMap<Integer, Float>();
            String userDefaultPrefix[] = prefix.split("~");
            }


        }
    }
}
```

I have the strings stored in userDefaultPrefix, and i need to add those values into prefixMap. TIA

Comment: A "map" maps things -- A => B.  So what do you intend to map to what?

Comment: prefixMap is a `Map<Integer,Float>` while elements in userDefaultPrefix are `String`s, you should explain how you want these elements to be added, and give a sample input, in order to get better answers.

Comment: @Amit ---  I apologize, Its a prefixMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

Comment: @Jeyaprakash: and what should the integer be? 1,...,userDefaultPrefix.length ? 0,...useDefaultPrefix.length-1? or something completely different?

Comment: Also, somewhat unrelated, but you seem to be using double-checked locking in an unsafe way. You are probably planning to access `prefixMap` outside the `synchronized` block. For correctness, you should use a `ConcurrentHashMap` or a `Collections.synchronizedMap()` instead of the regular `HashMap` and ensure that both the `loaded` and the `prefixMap` variable are declared `volatile`. Also, `loaded=true;` should come at the end of the block.

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right and you're sure in data quality than you can fill prefixMap following way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < userDefaultPrefix.length; i += 2) {
    if (i+1 < userDefaultPrefix.length) {
        prefixMap.put(Integer.parseInt(userDefaultPrefix[i]),
                Float.parseFloat(userDefaultPrefix[i+1]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you want a map of (i->userDefaultPrefix[i]):

```
for (int i = 0; i < userDefaultPrefix.length;i++) {
   prefixMap.put(i,userDefaultPrefix[i]); //note that the autoboxing automatically boxes your int to an Integer
}
```